# How can I solve "out of stock" in magento?

Tags: magento, stock

I have build magento website.
But I add products but their quantity are showed as out of stock.
what should I do?
Please help me.

I want to show the quantity as in stock.

Answer (score 0):

First it is necessary to validate some product data

Access your store's administrative panel at: Catalog => Products

- Select the product that has the error
- Check if the value of the “quantity” attribute is greater than 0
- Check if the value of the “stock status” attribute is “in stock”

If everything is ok, a possible error could be the lack of indexing of the catalog, to validate this probability go to: System => Index Manager

- Change indexing mode to “update on save” of indexes: stock, catalog product rule, product catalog, category products, and inventory

After checking the indexes, access your product again and click on the “save” button, clear all store caches in: System => Manage Cache and check if the product now appears as “in stock”

If the error persists, it is necessary to carry out a more technical analysis, analyze possible error logs when indexing the store and check the status of the indexes via ssh

Some useful commands are:

Display status of indexes:

php bin/magento indexer:status

Reindex:

php bin/magento indexer:reindex